# Laravel how to set up table with location and rate star

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to create a table where it consist of rating for example a rating of a location. Do i need to define the rate column inside the table ?

Comment: Probably not a complete answer to your question, but you might want to check out this library https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable, the documentation is simple to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any data type associated with a table needs to have a column on that table, yes

Here's what the table migration should look like

```php
Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->tinyInteger('rating');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And since this is a star rating system, you can display the rating in the view with stars and half stars like this (using fontawesome)

```html
<div class="location-star">
    @for ($i = 0; $i < floor($location->rating / 2); $i++)
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    @endfor
    @if ($location->rating % 2)
        <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
    @endif
</div>
```

So you can have a location rated 3 stars and half or 5 stars or 1 star or no stars at all, so the rating integer should be maximum 10
Hope this helps

Comment: say that it is a post table. would it still be the same ?

Comment: Yes, just change the name